# Как определить точку входа в процесс по объектному файлу ELF формата на Linux?

Tags: elf, linux

Как определить точку входа в процесс по объектному файлу ELF формата на Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если точка входа в процесс есть, то она задается в поле e_entry заголовка ELF файла.